# JQuery validation plugin maxlength?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery validation plugin. I want to specify `maxlength` for one of the fields.It can be specified as below.

```
rules: {
   Message: {
      required: false,
      maxLength: 200
   }
}
```

But instead of defining the rules externally, i want to specify the rules inside html input code

Similar to :

```
<input type="text" name="AssistanPhone" value="" class="required"  />
```

In above example "required" is specified through class. Similarly how can i specifiy maxlength which can be recognized by jquery plugin and gives error message if length exceeds?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not capital `L` its `l`

Ex:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 200
    }
  }
});
```

[**PLUGIN DEMO**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/)

Comment: Suresj, Thanks for your reply. how can i specify it inside html input tag? similar to class="required"? i dont want to define external rules and messages.

Comment: @user755806 Yes.See the full example in the link.

Comment: <input type="text" name="AssistanPhone" value="" class="required"  maxlength="4" />

Comment: Suresh, can't i avoid specifying maxlength through rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 200
    }
  }

Comment: As an example, to specify whether the field is required or not, am not using any rules. i am specifying isnide input element using class="required" . similarly cis it possible to specify for maxlength?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see you cannot specify the messages via attributes, but the `maxlength` can be specified as a attribute

```
<input type="text" name="AssistanPhone" value="" required maxlength="3"  />
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yNhJD/)

Comment: It wont show any error message to user.Simply stops user to type further.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the javascript code of the validator myself (so I'm stuck with my version 1.8.1 now instead of upgrading), but here's what I did (around line 767):

```
classRules: function(element) {
    var rules = {};
    var classes = $(element).attr('class');
    classes && $.each(classes.split(' '), function() {
        if (this in $.validator.classRuleSettings) {
            $.extend(rules, $.validator.classRuleSettings[this]);
        }
        if (this.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf('maxlength-', 0) === 0) { // starts with
            var x = parseInt(this.substring(10)); // take number after 'maxlength-'
            $.extend(rules, {maxlength: x});
        }
    });
    return rules;
},
```

I added the extra if-test for "maxlength-", so now I can add a class like "maxlength-10" to limit to 10. Of course I could also add minlength and so on.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $("#FormID").validate({
        rules: {
            PriorityDDL: {
                required: true
            },
            Title: {
                required: true
            },
            Text: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 300
            },

            date: {
                required: true
            },
            reportfile: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            PriorityDDL: {
                required: "Please select priority"
            },
            Title: {
                required: "Please enter title"
            },
            Text: {
                required: "Please enter message",
                maxlength:"maxLength is 300 characters"
            },
            date: {
                required: "Please select date"
            },
            reportfile: {
                required: "Please select file"
            }
        }
    });
```